# GAE Python: Webapp2 Equivalent of Flask request.data

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

I had to convert certain Python Flask code to Webapp2 code (used in GAE).

**Flask code snippet**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    post_body = urlencode(request.data)
```

**ATTEMPT 1**

```
if self.request.method == 'POST': 
    post_body = urllib.urlencode (self.request.data)
```

**ERROR**

```
:: 
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/1.378592258368936474/main_v3.py", line 1397, in post
    post_body = urllib.urlencode (self.request.data)
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webob-1.1.1/webob/request.py", line 1238, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: data
```

**ATTEMPT 2**

```
if self.request.method == 'POST': 
    post_body = urllib.urlencode (self.request.body_file)
```

**ERROR**

```
:: 
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/1.378591983192817348/main_v3.py", line 1397, in post
    post_body = urllib.urlencode (self.request.body_file) 
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1292, in urlencode
    if len(query) and not isinstance(query[0], tuple):
TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object
```

**ATTEMPT 3**

```
if self.request.method == 'POST': 
    post_body = urllib.urlencode (self.request.body)
```

**ERROR**

```
:: 
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/1.378592109110666000/main_v3.py", line 1397, in post
  post_body = urllib.urlencode (self.request.body) 
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1293, in urlencode
  raise TypeError
TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object
```

What is the correct Webapp2 equivalent of Flask request.data ?

---

**UPDATE**
I do not know Python Flask. I work with GAE Python. I am trying to convert the sample code provided in Google Identity Toolkit (Gitkit).
From [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.data),

> request.data
>
> Contains the incoming request data as string in case it came with a
>   mimetype Flask does not handle.

As per [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode),

> urllib.urlencode ()
>
> Convert a mapping object or a sequence of two-element tuples to a
>   “percent-encoded” string, suitable to pass to urlopen() above as the
>   optional data argument. This is useful to pass a dictionary of form
>   fields to a POST request. The resulting string is a series of
>   key=value pairs separated by '&' characters, where both key and value
>   are quoted using quote_plus() above. When a sequence of two-element
>   tuples is used as the query argument, the first element of each tuple
>   is a key and the second is a value. The value element in itself can be
>   a sequence and in that case, if the optional parameter doseq is
>   evaluates to True, individual key=value pairs separated by '&' are
>   generated for each element of the value sequence for the key. The
>   order of parameters in the encoded string will match the order of
>   parameter tuples in the sequence. The urlparse module provides the
>   functions parse_qs() and parse_qsl() which are used to parse query
>   strings into Python data structures.

I tried `urllib2.quote (self.request.body)` and no Python errors came. But, Gitkit rejected the response saying it was invalid. This implies that `urllib2.quote (self.request.body)` is not the right Python Webapp2 equivalent of Python Flask `urlencode(request.data)`.

Comment: I don't know much about flask, but I played on the app engine enough to probably be able to help... can you just explain what "urlencode(request.data)" does in flask?

Comment: @Julldar Thanks for your reply. I have updated the question with more data including the one asked by you. Please take a look (UPDATE section at the end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're attempting to parse the POST request body as a collection of URL-encoded parameters (such as what is submitted by a web form), the library parses these for you, and you can just access them with a `dict`-like interface (actually a `MultiDict` since a key can have more than one value):

```
field_value = self.request.POST['fieldname']
```

If you want the raw data, the `body` field gives you a useful string value.  The error you're getting from `urlencode()` is because that method does not take a string argument, it takes a mapping or a sequence of two-tuples.  Maybe this is what you're after:

```
post_body = urllib.urlencode(self.request.POST.items())
```

http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/reference.html#query-post-variables
https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode

Comment: (Technically `body` is already equivalent to the URL-encoded `post_body` if it starts out well-formed, but you might need to guard against malformed or malicious input, depending on your use case.)

Comment: +1 and Thanks. I think `post_body = urllib.urlencode(self.request.POST.items())` should be the answer. I m no longer getting Python errors but am getting Gitkit error message. I am investigating to confirm that it is a Gitkit problem. Once confirmed, I would mark your answer as accepted.